# What is the Pointy Part of a Speech Bubble Called?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, image-identification

Given a speech bubble, what is the pointy part from which indicates the origin of the spoken word?

[image]

I'm assuming this is the same term for thought bubbles? If not what's the term for the origin of thought bubbles?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to wikipedia, it's a **tail**:

> ... uses a bubble with a pointer, called a tail, directed towards the speaker.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_balloon)

I can't find a definitive source, and Wikiepdia doesn't provide one. But it's used in the sites like [this](https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-speech-bubbles-and-comic-effects-in-adobe-illustrator--cms-24764) and elsewhere.

> A common speech bubble is usually made up of a oval shape, with a tail at the bottom, indicating which person is the speaker.

There doesn't appear to be a distinction among the different versions of speech bubbles, so for a thought bubble, tail is still appropriate.

Comment: Also, Microsoft platforms use the term Callout for the whole shape.

Comment: Plenty of usage on this page if you want to add a citation: 
https://blog.animaker.com/speech-bubbles-meaning-in-animated-videos/

Answer (score 0):

it's Notch. Well pronounced as speak bubble notch.

Comment: Welcome! Do you have a reference for that? A dictionary entry, perhaps, or do you know it by personal experience?

Comment: I wouldn't mind giving an upvote or even accepting if you could provide a source. As it stands I've gotten used to calling it a tail.