# Is there a word for the arrow/pointer of a speech bubble

Tags: meaning, terminology

A speech bubble points to the person articulating the speech. The bubble itself is a square, but what is the arrow that points to the speaker called?

Comment: Welcome to ELU, this question has been asked before (it's the 'tail' by the way):  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/379265/what-is-the-pointy-part-of-a-speech-bubble-called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually referred to simply as the **tail**

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_balloon) (but acknowledging that the article would benefit from better citations):

> The most common is the speech bubble. It comes in two forms for two circumstances: an in-panel character and an off-panel character. An in-panel character (one who is fully or mostly visible in the panel of the strip of comic that the reader is viewing) uses a bubble with a pointer, called a tail, directed towards the speaker.

Comment: I've edited to attribute your quoted passage (which copyright regulations require) and add the caveat (Wikipedia is very good at acknowledging / estimating the truth-value of its claims), 330.

Comment: Given that the "bubble" is also sometimes referred to as a "balloon", I might call it a "string".